# wait until .html() has loaded and then do something

Tags: jquery

I have seen a few threads and they all say that html() is a synchronous event so you just need to put your code after it, but all my alerts appear before the content is shown.

I have reverted to alerts as an click event I wanted to put on the loaded content wasn't working.

```
var URL = '@Url.Content("~/Controller/_Action")';

$.ajax({
                url: URL,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (partialViewResult) {
                    $("#SideBarContent").html(partialViewResult);
                    alert('first')

                }                
            }).done(function () {
                alert('second');
            })
            alert('third');
```

all three alerts pop up, then the content loads.

I have also tried,

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();

            $.when(d1).then(function () {
                alert('loaded');
            });

            d1.resolve(LoadSideBarContent(url));

<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadSideBarContent(url) {
        $("#SideBarContent").html();
        $("#SideBarContent").load(url);
    };
</script>
```

has something changed or is this different because I am using a partialview?

Comment: Have to test `load(url, complete)` callback?

Comment: you mean like

$("#SideBarContent").load(url, { id: null /*parameters*/ }, function (text, status, xhr) {
                
                alert('logged');
            });

yes

Answer (score 2):

> but all my alerts appear before the content is shown

The fact that you see an alert  , doesn't mean that the content is not in there / sent to be rendered.

Alert just blocks everything.

When you write something to the screen , it isn't written directly to the screen. It is sent to be rendered(!). There's a huge difference.

Anyway - If you want to see if the content is there you should do this :

```
$.ajax({
                url: URL,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (partialViewResult) {
                    $("#SideBarContent").html(partialViewResult);
                    console.log('first')

                }                
            }).done(function () {
                console.log('second');
            })
            console.log('third');
```

Also -  it is unclear what did you try to do in :

```
d1.resolve(LoadSideBarContent(url));


var d1 = $.Deferred();

            $.when(d1).then(function () {
                alert('loaded');
            });

            d1.resolve(LoadSideBarContent(url)); //<-- with what value you want to resolve  the Deffered object ?

<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadSideBarContent(url) {
        $("#SideBarContent").html();    //<---What's this ?
        $("#SideBarContent").load(url);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Once the side bar is rendered I have an onclick event to apply to the buttons rendered in the partialview, however when clicking the button they click event didn't not fire so I tried to back track to use alerts to see if the the html rendering after the events were called.

the issue with console.log is that it appears instantly with the partial view so i can't see that one works before the other...

Comment: @JQuery I'm sorry I don't follow you. please simplify your question to an working example using  jsbin.com.

Comment: I want to call a partial view and render the html in a side bar.  This will have buttons on it.  Once that is rendered I want to apply a script so when the a button is clicked it fires some custom logic.  However, the jquery isn't being applied to the button so I thought it was because the script was loading before the html